# Options for Database Managers for SQL Server and MDS

Tags: sql-server, database-management, master-data-services

I am looking at ways to visualize my database for non-technical end users. I want them to only have access to views (triggers can be put on views to enable updating) and let them add, delete and modify data. It should be a simple software (hopefully look and feel wise it will be a lot like Excel).

If anyone has used the Excel with MDS tool I do like that but its largest drawback is it cannot be used to edit views but only the normalized tables. This means a ot of tabs the users will have to go through.

The users wont have admin level access. All of our databases use SQL Server or MDS. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Ben Finn What is MDS??

Comment: Good question. Master Data Services. It is Microsoft's Master Data Management solution. It has some settings that prevent it from being treated like a normal database. I tried Navicat and it wouldn't connect. I believe this is because of the MDS settings.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is off-topic as the rule state: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it"

Comment: I would like to argue against that. I am not asking for a recommendation or opinion only for **options**. I am having trouble find any solutions that provide this functionality. Even if someone where to tell me what type of software I would need would be useful. Everything I have found so far is specific for an industry or designed for Management of the entire database.

Comment: Have you looked at Lightswitch, or any of the other RAD toolkits?  It sounds like you want users to interact with a data virtualization layer, and not the database itself.  IMO not a fan of MDS, minus for small amounts of Reference or true MASTER data.